# Visual Studio Replace using regular expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

Well, I just want to see if somebody can give me more hints about regular expressions and replace.

Yesterday I tested it a little bit, and discovered how to use it with result groups and stuff like this.

Example code:

```
dbResult.txDesc = obj.Desc;
dbResult.vlTotal = obj.vlTotal;
dbResult.xxxx = obj.xxxx;
```

**Find Regex:** `(dbResult\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,})\s\=\s(obj\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,})\;`

Where:

- `dbResult\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,}` is the result group 1
- `\s\=\s` are literal for the "`=`"
- `\;` is a literal for ";"
- `obj\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{0,}` is the result group 2

**Replace:** `$2 = $1`;

- `$1` is a reference for the group 1
- `$2` is a reference for the group 2

Then the result:

```
obj.Desc = dbResult.txDesc;
obj.vlTotal = dbResult.vlTotal;
obj.xxxx = dbResult.xxxx;
```

I want to make a documentation with hints about regex and replace in VS, because of this if someone can help.

Comment: SO is not the place to ask broad open ended questions like this, if you have a specific question about a regex you are having trouble with, that would be an appropriate question.

Comment: Sorry about this, I'm aware now, thanks.

Comment: Honestly, you need to do a lot more learning before explaining regular expressions to anyone else. Separately, `{0,}` is the same as using `*`. Both mean `zero or more times, as many times as possible while matching the rest of the expression` unless a `lazy` notation notation is used, in either form. Good luck, and feel free to ask *specific* questions about regex behavior. **I will say:** Good job on providing a detailed question. I made significant edits that will help you learn SO`s "`markdown`" syntax for formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS2012 and newer, it should use .NET Regular Expression syntax.  Prior to that, VS had its own slightly different syntax.  The differences are shown on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx).